# Algorithm to solve this Maze game

Tags: algorithm, sorting, flutter, dart, graph-algorithm

While learning flutter I have made a game Rabbit and maze which you can access from [this link](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.pallavbohara.fluttermaze).

**Game description:** There is 5 type of tiles in the game: Plus(+) shaped have four ways(or openings), T-shaped having three ways, L-shaped with two ways, I-shaped having two ways, brick-shaped don't have any way. In my game user have to make way from rabbit to home by tapping and rotating bricks. I have attached a 3x3 game screenshot (there are 4x4,5x5 etc levels).

[image].

Every-time game is randomly generated so in this screenshot you can see T and I shaped tiles. On every-tap tile rotates 90 degrees. To complete this game one has to make white path from rabbit to home(can be done by tapping top-right tile 2 times in this). Right now, the game does tells user if they have successfully made the path.

**Problem:** the game is randomly generated. So we don't know whether every game is solvable or not. I want to only show games that are solvable. I also have to show user the solution if he fails to solve it at the end with minimum steps.

Game-Cell-Modal:

```
 class GameCellModal {
  AngleDegree angle; //can have 0,90,180,270
  IconCode icon;
  int row; 
  int column;
  int rowLength; // max length for eg 3 for 3x3
  int columnLength; // max length for eg 3 for 3x3
}
```

Comment: for small number of tiles you can use backtracking ... (testing all the combinations)

Comment: My game can maximum goes to 8x8. Testing all combination means complexity of 8^64. Can I consider this number small?

Comment: with some heuristics yes ...

Comment: Do you want the solution with the least rotations or with the least distance? Or is there some trade-off between the two?

Comment: @trincot least rotation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a variant of Dijkstra's algorithm. Convert the grid to a graph, where a node is a grid cell, and a node has up to four neighbors (irrespective of the content of the cell). 
The actual neighbors that can be reached, depend on where the path came from, and the content of the cell. Generate all possibilities to find the next edge that can be traversed, and increase the cost of the path if a rotation was needed to go to a certain direction. Don't allow a path to revisit a node it already has.

You need to store the paths in a priority queue (based on total rotation cost), but as we know that the total cost is limited (< 3 x #cells), you can use an array for this, where the index is the cost, and the value is the list of paths having that cost.

You can then iterate that array from index 0 onward, and deal with the paths in that order. This will assure you will find the shortest path.

The time complexity is not as good as a standard Dijkstra algorithm, as you cannot prohibit that the same cell is visited via different paths. However, you must still check that the *same* path does not visit the same cell.

For representation of the grid and the graph there are many possibilities. Here I have chose to use box-drawing characters for grid contents, as during debugging you can easily see what the cell content represents.

I think the above description should be enough to get the idea, but in case you need to see an implementation, I add here one in JavaScript. It is interactive, so you can generate random 8x8 grids, and see the algorithm work through the grid.

```js
// Characters that will be used as cell content:
let box = " SE╝ ═╚╩ ╗║╣╔╦╠╬";
// blank = brick, S = start, E = end.
// The position of the character is a 4 bit number. Each bit represents a direction
// (east, north, west, south), and is set to 1 when that direction is enabled.
// Exceptions are S and E which have all four directions enabled.

// Determine which rotations make sense for each character.
let rotations = { 
    " ": [] // A brick has no rotations
};
for (let i = 1; i < 16; i++) {
    let chr = box[i];
    if (chr == " ") continue;
    let rot = [];
    let j = i;
    if ("╬SE".includes(chr)) { // rotating does not change anything
        rot.push(0xF);
    } else { // can turn 90° to different shape
        rot.push(j, j = bitRotate(j));
        if (!"═║".includes(chr)) { // shape has more than two states
            rot.push(j = bitRotate(j), bitRotate(j)); 
        }
    }
    rotations[chr] = rot;
}

class Node {
    constructor(name, row, col, chr) {
        this.name = name;
        this.row = row;
        this.col = col;
        this.chr = chr;
        // One potential entry for each direction: East, North, West, South
        this.neighbors = [null, null, null, null];
    }
    addNeighbor(direction, neighbor) {
        if (!neighbor) return;
        this.neighbors[direction] = neighbor;
        neighbor.neighbors[direction ^ 2] = this; // reverse direction
    }
}

function createGraph(grid) {
    let height = grid.length;
    let width = grid[0].length;
    let startNode = null;
    let nodes = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < height; i++) {
        for (let j = 0; j < width; j++) {
            if (grid[i][j] == " ") {
                nodes[j] = null;
            } else {
                let node = new Node(JSON.stringify([i, j]), i, j, grid[i][j]);
                // if there is a node left, log it as neighbor
                if (j > 0) node.addNeighbor(0, nodes[j-1]);
                // if there is a node above, log it as neighbor
                if (i > 0) node.addNeighbor(1, nodes[j]);
                if (node.chr == "S") startNode = node;
                nodes[j] = node;
            }
        }
    }
    return startNode;
}

function extendPath(path) {
    let node = path[path.length-1];
    // Get direction (bit) at which we entered last node in path
    let entry = 1;
    if (path.length > 1) entry = 1 << node.neighbors.indexOf(path[path.length-2]);
    let rot = rotations[node.chr];
    let exits = 0;
    let remainingExits = 0xF;
    let paths = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < rot.length && remainingExits > 0; i++) {
        if ((rot[i] & entry) == 0) continue; // Cannot enter at this rotation
        let exits = (rot[i] ^ entry) & remainingExits;
        remainingExits ^= exits;
        let j = 0;
        while (exits) {
            let neighbor = node.neighbors[j];
            // Can exit in direction j? Only when:
            // - rotation allows it
            // - there is an edge (not off-grid; not visited before)
            // - not going to a node that is already on this path
            if ((exits & 1) && neighbor && !path.includes(neighbor)) {
                paths.push([i, path.concat(neighbor)]);
            }
            exits >>= 1;
            j++;
        }
    }
    return paths;
}

// Use delays so the algorithm's progress can be visualised
const delay = () => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 10));

async function shortestPath(grid, listener) {
    // Convert to an easier to use data structure:
    let startNode = createGraph(grid);
    // As a BFS priority queue, use an array indexed by total made rotations,
    // and for each index, store a list of paths that use that many rotations.
    // The maximum number of rotations per node is 3, so the total made rotations
    // cannot be more than 3 times the number of cells in the grid.
    let paths = []; // This is a dynamicly growing array
    paths[0] = [[startNode]]; // Initial path has 0 rotations and has just the start node.
    for (let cost = 0; cost < paths.length; cost++) {
        let cheapPaths = paths[cost] || [];
        for (let j = 0; j < cheapPaths.length; j++) {
            let path = cheapPaths[j];
            if (path.length > 1) {
                // Check that the edge was not yet visited
                let [prev, curr] = path.slice(path.length-2); // get last two nodes
                let dir = prev.neighbors.indexOf(curr);
                if (dir < 0) continue; // edge was already visited
                // Visit the directed edge by removing it from the graph
                prev.neighbors[dir] = null;
            }
            if (listener) {
                listener(path.map(node => [node.row, node.col]));
                await delay();
            }
            // Did we reach the target?
            if (path[path.length-1].chr == "E") return cost;
            for (let [rotation, nextPath] of extendPath(path)) {
                let newCost = cost + rotation;
                if (!paths[newCost]) paths[newCost] = []; // extend array
                paths[newCost].push(nextPath);
            }
        }
    }
    return Infinity; // no solution found
}

function generateGrid(width, height) {
    let grid = Array.from({length: height}, () => 
        Array.from({length: width}, () => " ╝═╚╩╗║╣╔╦╠╬"[Math.floor(Math.random() * 12)])
    );
    // For this demo, we always put the start/end nodes in the opposite corners
    grid[0][0] = "S"; // starting node
    grid[7][7] = "E"; // ending node
    return grid;
}

function bitRotate(bits) { // Rotate 4 bits:
    return ((bits << 1) | +(bits >= 8)) & 0xF;
}

// All below is for I/O handling with DOM

(function () {
    let table = document.querySelector("#game");
    let msg = document.querySelector("#msg");
    let btnScramble = document.querySelector("#scramble");
    let btnSolve = document.querySelector("#solve");
    let grid;

    function newGame() {
        grid = generateGrid(8, 8);
        display();
    }

    function display(path=[]) {
        // Create HTML table contents from scratch
        table.innerHTML = grid.map(row =>
            `<tr>${row.map(chr => `<td>${htmlBox(chr)}<\/td>`).join("")}<\/tr>`
        ).join("");
        // If a path argument was given, then color that path
        let cost = 0;
        for (let i = 0; i < path.length; i++) {
            let p = path[i];
            let numRotations = 0;
            if (i > 0 && i < path.length-1) {
                numRotations = rotationCount(grid, path[i-1], p, path[i+1], path[path.length-1].join() === "7,7");
            }
            table.rows[p[0]].cells[p[1]].style.backgroundColor = 
                ["yellow", "orange", "red", "purple"][numRotations];
            cost += numRotations;
        }
        if (path.length) {
            msg.textContent = "Used " + cost + " rotations...";
        } else {
            msg.textContent = "";
        }
    }
    
    async function solve() {     
        btnScramble.disabled = true;
        btnSolve.disabled = true;
        // As the algorithm progresses, call display
        let cost = await shortestPath(grid, display);
        msg.textContent = cost === Infinity ? "No path found" : "Minimal number of rotations = " + cost;
        btnScramble.disabled = false;
        btnSolve.disabled = false;
    }

    newGame(); // immediately create a game on page load

    btnScramble.addEventListener("click", newGame);
    btnSolve.addEventListener("click", solve);

    table.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
        if (btnSolve.disabled) return; // do not allow changing the grid while solving
        let td = e.target.closest("#game>tbody>tr>td");
        if (!td) return;
        rotate(grid, td.cellIndex, td.parentNode.rowIndex);
        display();
    });
})();

function rotate(grid, x, y) {
    let chr = grid[y][x];
    if ("SE╬ ".includes(chr)) return false; // nothing to turn
    let bits = box.indexOf(chr);
    grid[y][x] = box[bitRotate(bits)];
    return true;
}

function rotationCount(grid, a, b, c) {
    let entry = a[1] < b[1] ? 1 
              : a[1] > b[1] ? 4
              : a[0] < b[0] ? 2 : 8;
    let exit  = c[1] < b[1] ? 1
              : c[1] > b[1] ? 4
              : c[0] < b[0] ? 2 : 8;
    let needed = entry + exit;
    let actual = box.indexOf(grid[b[0]][b[1]]);
    for (let count = 0; count < 4; count++) {
        if ((actual & needed) == needed) return count;
        actual = bitRotate(actual);
    }
    throw "rotation not found";
}

function htmlBox(chr) {
    if (chr == "S") return "";
    if (chr == "E") return "";
    let bits = box.indexOf(chr);
    return "<table>"
        + `<tr><td class="black"><\/td><td class="${color(bits, 2)}"><\/td><td class="black"><\/td><\/tr>`
        + `<tr><td class="${color(bits, 1)}"><\/td><td class="white"><\/td><td class="${color(bits, 4)}"><\/td><\/tr>` 
        + `<tr><td class="black"><\/td><td class="${color(bits, 8)}"><\/td><td class="black"><\/td><\/tr>`
    + "</table>";
}

function color(bits, bit) {
    return bits & bit ? "white" : "black";
}
```

```css
table { border-collapse: collapse }
td { padding: 0; border: 1px solid grey; text-align: center }

#game { margin-right: 10px; float: left }
#game table td { border-width: 0px; }
#game table tr:first-child, #game table tr:last-child { height: 6px }
#game table tr:nth-child(2) { height: 12px }
#game table td:first-child, #game table td:last-child { width: 6px }
#game table td:nth-child(2) { width: 12px }

#game .black { background: black }

button { margin-right: 10px }

body { margin: 0 }
```

```html
<table id="game"></table>
<button id="scramble">Scramble</button><button id="solve">Solve</button><br>
Yellow = no rotation, Orange=1, Red=2, Purple=3

<div id="msg"></div>
```

Comment: You are brilliant! This is exactly what I needed. Thanks from bottom of heart :)